# Using php curl code second time before first response

Tags: php, multithreading, curl

I found few similar questions, but couldn't fit my needs.
I send request via curl to payment terminal.
my request example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PosXML version="7.1.0">
  <TransactionReq>
    <Amount>100</Amount>
    <CurrencyName>EUR</CurrencyName>
  </TransactionReq>
</PosXML>"
```

My code:

```
    $header = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml",
        "Content-length: " . strlen($this->dataXML),
        "Connection: close",
    );
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->terminal_ip);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->waitCardTimeout + $this->pinInputTimeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->dataXML);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $this->terminal_port);
    
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
        $error = curl_error($ch);
    } else {
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($data, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    return $array;
```

After first request terminal initiates payment. And only way to cancel it is to send other request to terminal, before first is finished.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PosXML version="7.1.0">
  <CancelAllOperationsReq>
  </CancelAllOperationsReq>
</PosXML>"
```

Is there a way?
P.s. Sorry for my english. I hope my problem is understandable.

Comment: Why do you wish to cancel the payment if you have just initiated the payment?

Comment: Imagine sometimes when you go shopping and remember that you have no wallet when the cashier have already cecked your goods. The cashier should have ant option to cancel the request and not wait for timeout to happen